# Copy & paste embeded object to file system

Tags: c#

Cross-post at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8669c828-4919-43cc-b1ce-03c0b03def6e/copy-paste-embeded-object-to-file-system?forum=exceldev

Background:

I wrote a large piece of VBA code in an Excel workbook to help handle a lot of repeating jobs. I found it is painful to maintain and modify the code by using the "pool" VBA Editor. Then, I decided to move those VBA code to C# solutions, which I suppose I can benefit from the modern editor - Visual Studio.

Problem:

Although I don't know too much about VBA, I know even less about C#. Hence I got some problem when I try to "translate" my VBA code to C#, and here is one of them:

I create a document-level solution for Excel.
I need to embed some files (.cab, .exe) into the solution, so when I run a method (e.g. by clicking a button), those files will be copied to the file system, and do some job.

In VBA, I embedded those files in the Excel workbook, then I can copy the embedded objects to the clipboard by using the following VBA code:

```
Sheet1.OLEObjects("obj_cab").COpy
```

And then I can paste the object to the file system by using the following VBA code:

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Sample\").Self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
```

In the C# solution, I can use the following equivalent method to copy the embedded object to the clipboard:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEObject OLEobj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEObject)sheet1.OLEObjects("obj_cab");
OLEobj.Copy();
```

Then I stuck here, I don't know how to get this object from clipboard and put it to the file system. The 'CreateObject' method does not exist in C#.

Anyone can help? Either a better way to embed those files or a working way to paste those objects (files) from clipboard to the file system?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Option Explicit

Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
ByVal HWnd As Long, _
ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, _
lParam As Any) As Long

Public Const WM_CLOSE As Long = &H10
Public Const IE_WINDOW_CLASS = "IEFrame"

Sub CloseAllInternetExplorer()

Dim HWnd As Long
HWnd = FindWindow(IE_WINDOW_CLASS, vbNullString)
Do Until HWnd = 0
SendMessage HWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&
HWnd = FindWindow(IE_WINDOW_CLASS, vbNullString)
Loop

End Sub

Public Sub CloseIE()
    Dim Shell As Object
    Dim IE As Object

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each IE In Shell.Windows
    If TypeName(IE.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        IE.Quit
    End If
Next
```

End Sub